# primefaces p:button issues

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i am getting this error in glassfish when i click on my button

```
WARNING: #{UserBean.buttonToTutorial}: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /GUI/index.xhtml @61,77 action="#{UserBean.buttonToTutorial}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'UserBean' resolved to null
```

the code is :

```
                <p:commandButton action="#{UserBean.buttonToTutorial}"/>
```

in the xhtml file

and in UserBean.java

```
    public String buttonToTutorial() {
    System.out.println("buttonToTutorial invoked");
    return "tutorial.xhtml";
}
```

What i am trying to do is just a fancy way to take the user from one page to another, what have i got wrong ?

UserBean.java is located in root / richard.fileupload/UserBean.java

Comment: Try to change UserBean to userBean in el in your xhtml file.

Comment: That done it ! thanks ! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `UserBean` to `userBean` in xhtml file. Default name for managed bean is class name with lower first letter.